# wpdb not inserting row into the table

Tags: php, wordpress

i have a form that allows input of name ,email & photo...when i click on submit i want it to insert a row into the posttype called'contact' with the info submitted the by the form and the image as the featured image but it does nothing

my code

```
<?php

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {    

     $yourname=$_POST['yourname'];
     $email=$_POST['email'];
     $myimage=$_POST['myimage'];    

    include_once('../../../wp-config.php');
    global $wpdb;
    $table = 'wp_posts';
    $data  = array(
    post_title=>$yourname,  
    post_status=>'Published', 
    post_type=>'contacts',  
    email=>$email,
    featured_image=>$myimage
    );
    $wpdb->insert( $table, $data);

}   

 ?>
<form action="" method="POST">
         Your Name: <input type="text" name="yourname" value=""> <br>
         Your Email:  <input type="text" name="email" value=""> <br>
         Image: <input type="file" name="myimage" id=""><br>    
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />           
</form>
```

is there any way i can check if row is uploaded & echo a message if insert is done and then redirect to a new url after few seconds.

Comment: add some quotes  to your `$data` indexes

Comment: $yourname is variable holding the text tht doesn't need quotes

Comment: I was actually talking about the part before `=>`

Answer (score 0):

Check if columns passed on `$data` exists in database or in form don't have `method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"`, try insert this.

Answer (score 0):

You can not get the value of uploaded files from the `$_POST` variable. For that you need to use `$_FILES` variable.

To make that code work first you have to add following :

1. In the form tag you need to add `method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"`.
2. In the the PHP script where you get the value of image, Use this code to get the value of image.

`featured_image => $_FILES['myimage']['name']`